# What causes clang: error: unsupported option '--serialize-diagnostics' with xcode

Tags: xcode, clang

I am trying to execute the clang analyser with an Xcode build. This worked on another project, but now I get the error described below. Has anyone seen this?

**MY COMMAND LINE:**

> /Users/builder/Tools/checker-267/scan-build -k -v -o scan_output
>   xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos
>   CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=build 'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone
>   Distribution:'
>
> I GET (THOUGH THIS WARNING ALSO APPEARED WITH A PREVIOUS PROJECT THAT
>   COMPLETED LINTING SUCCESSFULLY):
>
> Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'ccc-analyzer' compiler's built-in
>   search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect
>   'objective-c'.
>
> AND THEN GET THE unsupported option '--serialize-diagnostics' ERROR
>   WHICH SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM:
>
> Details:  Unable to get message category info for tool
>   '/Users/builder/Tools/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer'. Reason: Can't
>   exec "clang": No such file or directory at
>   /Users/builder/Tools/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer line 428.
>
> Object:    Method:
>   -messageCategoryInfoForExecutablePath: Thread:   {name = (null), num = 5} Please file a bug at
>   http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful
>   information you can provide. clang: error: unsupported option
>   '--serialize-diagnostics' clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Civitas-cjaysrhpylwnfoaagvkzrnpvmkhq/Build/Intermediates/HAClient.build/Release-iphoneos/HAClient.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HAClient.dia'
>   Command /Users/builder/Tools/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer failed
>   with exit code 1

THANKS for suggestion but it still fails. I get:

Check dependencies

2012-07-20 13:55:23.195 xcodebuild[25585:352f] error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "Non-zero exit code 255 returned from shell command: /Users/builder/Tools/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1" UserInfo=0x4001c0b40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Non-zero exit code 255 returned from shell command: /Users/builder/Tools/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1, NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such file or directory}
2012-07-20 13:55:23.197 xcodebuild[25585:352f] Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'ccc-analyzer' compiler's built-in search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect 'objective-c'.
Compiler: /Users/builder/Tools/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer
Reason:   /Users/builder/Tools/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by compiling for arm (`-sdk iphoneos`). Change the sdk to `-sdk iphonesimulator` and all will be fine.